# Is there a clearer / better way of counting the number of distinct items by field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wish to write a generic function that given a queryset returns the number of distinct fields for each column of the model.

The function I have so far is:

`[queryset.aggregate(Count(x, distinct=True)) for x in [x.get_attname() for x in queryset.model._meta._fields()]]`

However this is rather hacky / ugly / unclear. I'm wondering if there is a simpler / clearer way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Without further analyse of what the used methods do: `[ queryset.aggregate(Count(x.get_attname(), distinct=True)) for x in queryset.model._meta._fields() ]`

Comment: That is shorter (and more efficient), although I'm not sure about clearer. I was sort of hoping there was a `queryset.variance()` function.

Comment: that's possible. I don't know `queryset`, I just did a simple Python optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass [more than one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) aggregate to `.aggregate`, so you could do that to reduce calls to the database.
The code below is untested and only supposed to give an idea of what I mean.

```
args = [Count(x.get_attname(), distinct=True)) for x in queryset.model._meta._fields()]
queryset.aggregate(*args)
```